# On load Set value for sweet alert input

Tags: sweetalert

In sweet alert 2, How on load to set value in input 
my sweet alert code

```
swal({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
              text: "You are going to send emails from the system. Please confirm",                   
              showCancelButton: true,
              input: 'email',

              confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
              confirmButtonColor: '#4aa0f1',
              cancelButtonColor: '#898b8e',
              confirmButtonText: 'Send'
            }).then(function (email) {  
                send_email = email;
                sentHtmtBody_send();
                loadingIcon();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sweetalert2 I implement it in this [suggested way](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#content):

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = 'test';
input.type = 'text';
input.className = 'swal-content__input';
swal('Please type:', {
    content: input,
    buttons: ['Cancel', 'Update']
})
.then(() => {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 10):

We can add another field

```
inputValue : 'test value',
```

after adding it full code we can see it like this

```
swal({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
              text: "You are going to send emails from the system. Please confirm",                   
              showCancelButton: true,
              input: 'email',
              inputValue: "E.g john",
              confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
              confirmButtonColor: '#4aa0f1',
              cancelButtonColor: '#898b8e',
              confirmButtonText: 'Send'
            }).then(function (email) {  
                send_email = email;
                sentHtmtBody_send();
                loadingIcon();
            });
```